# unable to run flutter new pj on simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

when I tried to run the preset code from flutter
I got this error and I have no idea how to fix it
I tried to run flutter clean flutter upgrade but no help

Error (Xcode): lib/main.dart:35:19: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'MyHomePage'.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.0, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
• Flutter version 3.10.0 on channel stable at /Users/standbyu/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 84a1e904f4 (4 days ago), 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
• Engine revision d44b5a94c9
• Dart version 3.0.0
• DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14E222b
• CocoaPods version 1.12.1